# python multiprocessing pool notification on worker refreshing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, process-pool

I'm using Python 2.7's `multiprocessing.Pool` to manage a pool of 3 workers. Each worker is fairly complicated and there's a resource leak (presumably) in some third-party code that causes problems after 6-8 hours of continuous runtime. So I'd like to use `maxtasksperchild` to have workers refreshed periodically.

I'd also like each worker to write to its own separate log file. Without `maxtasksperchild` I use a shared `multiprocessing.Value` to assign an integer (0, 1, or 2) to each worker, then use the integer to name the log file.

With `maxtasksperchild` I'd like to reuse log files once a worker is done. So if this whole thing runs for a month, I only want three log files, not one log file for each worker that was spawned.

If I could pass a callback (e.g. a `finalizer` to go along with the `initializer` currently supported), this would be straightforward. Without that, I can't see a robust and simple way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's AFAIK undocumented, but `multiprocessing` has a `Finalizer` class, "which supports object finalization using weakrefs". You could use it to register a finalizer within your `initializer`.

I don't see `multiprocessing.Value` a helpful synchronization choice in this case, though. Multiple workers could exit simultaneously, signaling which file-integers are free is more than a (locked) counter could provide then.

I would suggest use of multiple bare `multiprocessing.Lock`s, one for each file, instead:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock, current_process
from multiprocessing.util import Finalize


def f(n):
    global fileno
    for _ in range(int(n)):  # xrange for Python 2
        pass
    return fileno


def init_fileno(file_locks):
    for i, lock in enumerate(file_locks):
        if lock.acquire(False):  # non-blocking attempt
            globals()['fileno'] = i
            print("{} using fileno: {}".format(current_process().name, i))
            Finalize(lock, lock.release, exitpriority=15)
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':

    n_proc = 3
    file_locks = [Lock() for _ in range(n_proc)]

    pool = Pool(
        n_proc, initializer=init_fileno, initargs=(file_locks,),
        maxtasksperchild=2
    )

    print(pool.map(func=f, iterable=[50e6] * 18))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    # all locks should be available if all finalizers did run
    assert all(lock.acquire(False) for lock in file_locks)
```

Output:

```
ForkPoolWorker-1 using fileno: 0
ForkPoolWorker-2 using fileno: 1
ForkPoolWorker-3 using fileno: 2
ForkPoolWorker-4 using fileno: 0
ForkPoolWorker-5 using fileno: 1
ForkPoolWorker-6 using fileno: 2
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Note that with Python 3 you can't use Pool's context-manager reliably instead of the old way of doing it shown above. Pool's context-manager (unfortunately) calls `terminate()`, which might kill worker-processes *before* the finalizer had a chance to run.

Comment: My concern here is that if a process is terminated (even under Python 2) then the lock won't be released.

Comment: @nonagon. That's true, but Pool will hang up with any method in general when a worker gets killed by the OS. Note that your solution also uses a lock, so it's not even theoretically different but adds OS-dependency on top of it.

Comment: @nonagon ...To elaborate on that, it will hang up because Pool is still waiting for outstanding tasks to finish which will never happen for terminated worker tasks. There are also more locks involved under the hood because worker's access to internal shared task-queues is _also_ guarded by locks. `multiprocessing.Pool` is not made to recover from a OS kill of one of it's workers. In case you meant "terminated due to hitting maxtaskperchild", that's not a termination but a clean voluntary exit from the worker, so there's no danger from that corner.

Comment: Yes good point - if my worker is terminated while I'm holding `child_pids.getlock()` I'm in trouble. That code is simple though, kind of like a bootloader - I'm concerned about an OS termination while the subsequent code is running, since in my real-world case the workers are very complicated. When this happened I found that the python 2.7 `multiprocessing.Pool` was able to spawn new workers to replace them (even without using `maxtasksperchild`). With your solution, I think the `Finalizer` wouldn't run so we'd never recover the `fileno` for the terminated process, let me know if you agree.

Comment: I checked the python 2.7 `multiprocessing.Pool` source and I see what you mean - there are internal locks for task queues to worry about. I think the locks are not held while the worker is actually doing the processing. In my case this is the time I'm worried about - since that's when I'm much much more likely to encounter OS termination of my worker processes.

Comment: @nonagon Yes Pool will replace terminated workers but you'll never get the result of a `Pool.map()` call for example, because Pool is still waiting for the result which will never come.

Comment: Aha I was using apply_async so it worked. I think my solution works in my particular case but yours is more generally useful so I’ll accept yours. Thanks for the comments and suggestions!

Comment: @nonagon You're welcome! It should still hang eventually for the killed job even with `.apply_async()`, though. Btw, `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` at least crashes immediately as soon a worker gets killed.

Comment: See also: [Guaranteed Finalization Without Context Manager](https://zpz.github.io/blog/guaranteed-finalization-without-context-manager/).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with the following. It assumes that PIDs aren't recycled very quickly (true on Ubuntu for me, but not in general on Unix). I don't think it makes any other assumptions, but I'm really just interested in Ubuntu so I didn't look at other platforms such as Windows carefully.

The code use an array to keep track of which PIDs have claimed which index. Then when a new worker is started, it looks to see if any PIDs are no longer in use. If it finds one, it assumes this is because the worker has completed its work (or been terminated for another reason). If it doesn't find one then we're out of luck! So this isn't perfect but I think its simpler than anything I've seen so far or considered.

```
def run_pool():
    child_pids = Array('i', 3)
    pool = Pool(3, initializser=init_worker, initargs=(child_pids,), maxtasksperchild=1000)

def init_worker(child_pids):
    with child_pids.get_lock():
        available_index = None
        for index, pid in enumerate(child_pids):
            # PID 0 means unallocated (this happens when our pool is started), we reclaim PIDs
            # which are no longer in use. We also reclaim the lucky case where a PID was recycled
            # but assigned to one of our workers again, so we know we can take it over
            if not pid or not _is_pid_in_use(pid) or pid == os.getpid():
                available_index = index
                break

        if available_index is not None:
            child_pids[available_index] = os.getpid()
        else:
            # This is unexpected - it means all of the PIDs are in use so we have a logical error
            # or a PID was recycled before we could notice and reclaim its index
            pass

def _is_pid_in_use(pid):
    try:
        os.kill(pid, 0)
        return True
    except OSError:
        return False
```